# everything going into flex-container

Tags: css, containers, flexbox

Really new to coding and I've been playing with flex container for a project I'm working on. The problem I'm having is that everything I put into the code after the container style seems to end up in the container. Im wondering how I can stop this or start a new container. heres the code Im looking at:

```
<style>
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
margin: 0px;
}

.flex-right{
float: right;
 background-color: none;
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;

}
.flex-left{
    background-color: none;
    width: 800px
    height: 100%;
    margin: 15px 90px;
float: left
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-left"><img src="sample trainer.png" width="400" height="475" alt="" border="0"></div>
  <div class="flex-right">
<h1><span style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 30pt;">Sample Text Here</span></h>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; text-decoration: none; font-size: 24pt;">More Sample Text here</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<div id="footer">Ending</div>
```

When i check it in my browser, I see the footer ends up in the flex.container

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to close your `flex-container` div with `</div>` before the footer. Make sure also to keep all your HTML before closing `</body>` tag. You've got other invalid code in there, like `</h>` instead of `</h1>`, so be careful to check your syntax.

Also avoid inline CSS (including those unnecessary `span` elements). And remember that you really don't want to float the contents of a flex container, as flex layout is really an alternative to float layout.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
margin: 0px;
}

.flex-right{
float: right;
 background-color: none;
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;

}
.flex-left{
    background-color: none;
    width: 800px
    height: 100%;
    margin: 15px 90px;
float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-left"><img src="sample trainer.png" width="400" height="475" alt="" border="0"></div>
  <div class="flex-right">
    <h1><span style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 30pt;">Sample Text Here</span>
    </h1>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; text-decoration: none; font-size: 24pt;">More Sample Text here</span></p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Ending</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the footer before you close your body and html.

Try this instead:

```
</div>
<div id="footer">Ending</div>
</body>
</html>
```